# How to disable hover to click on top bar?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gui, top-bar

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME. When I go to the top bar and click on the *Applications* button, the applications menu opens up. However, while taking the mouse to my required application, it often travels over the *Places* button, which automatically opens the places menu. I do not want this to happen.

How do I configure it so that a menu opens only when I click on it and not when I hover my mouse?

PS: The hover to click problem is only there when another menu on the top bar is already open. If no menus are open, then hovering doesn't do anything and I do have to click to open it.

Comment: Probably you will need to edit source code. It is how this is designed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Disable Menu Switching](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4133/disable-menu-switching/) extension.

Read this question about how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)